# Using Cuda for non-square matrix multiplication

Tags: c, matrix, cuda

I started to work with cuda the last days. Writing a program which multiplies two matrices of the size N x N was no problem. In the kernel function I used this code:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < width; i++){
        sum += a[row * width + i] * b[i * width + col];
        c[row * width + col] = sum;
    }
```

How do I have to design the kernel function to multiply a matrix of the size 1 x N with a matrix of the size N x M

Comment: `a matrix of the size N` - do you mean N x N ?

Comment: I don't understand the question here. The code you have shown, which is just the inner product of a row and a column (why is the store inside the loop?), doesn't change, irrespective of the other dimensions of the matrices involved.

Comment: No, i want to multiply a 1 dimensional matrix N with a 2 dimensional matrix N x M. The matrix where I store the results has to be M large.  @talonmies, I haven't changed the code above. It works fine to multiply two matrices of the size N x N. But for non-square matrices it doesn't although I have used the height paramter in the "a index"

Comment: Simplest thing would be padding both to square types and adding range checking in kernel to avoid unnecessary computing

Comment: You mean I should multiply a matrix of the size 1 x N with N x M don't you? I have tried this but I still get the wrong result. Here is the complete kernel now: https://justpaste.it/xxf3  What is wrong with my kernel?

Comment: Multplying a 1xN matrix by an NxM matrix to produce a 1xM matrix is commonly called a matrix-vector multiply.  If you're interested in performance, use cublas.  If you want to write your own code, as @talonmies indicated already, a matrix-matrix multiply kernel like the one you have shown should work.  If you can't make it work and want help, you probably should provide a [mcve], right here, in this question (not in an external link).  It should be a *complete* code, not just a kernel.

Answer (score -2):

I have found a solution for this problem now:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

__global__
void kernel(float *a, float *b, float *c, int N, int M) {
    int tid = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    float sum = 0;
    if (tid < M) {
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            sum += a[i] * b[(i * M) + tid];
        c[tid] = sum;

    }
}

int main(void) {

    float *dev_a, *dev_b, *dev_c;

    int N = 16;
    int M = 12;

    float a[N];
    float b[N][M];
    float c[M];

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        a[i] = 1.0;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (int e = 0; e < M; e++) {
            b[i][e] = 1.0;
        }
    }

    cudaMalloc((void**) &dev_a, sizeof(float) * N);
    cudaMalloc((void**) &dev_b, sizeof(float) * N * M);
    cudaMalloc((void**) &dev_c, sizeof(float) * M);

    cudaMemcpy(dev_a, a, sizeof(float) * N, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(dev_b, b, sizeof(float) * N * M, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    kernel<<<M / 256 + 1, 256>>>(dev_a, dev_b, dev_c, N, M);

    cudaMemcpy(c, dev_c, sizeof(float) * M, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    cudaFree(dev_a);
    cudaFree(dev_b);
    cudaFree(dev_c);

    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
        cout << c[i] << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

But I have still one question. Does it make sense to split the for loop operation in the kernel in several kernels for performance reasons?